# upload html file in smyfony2

Tags: file, symfony

I want to upload a html file using symfony but always I get an error

```
Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed
```

the code of my class docuement is given as follow

```
class document
{

    /* ... */

    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="filename", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $filename;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="realfilename", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $realfilename;

    /**
     * @Assert\File(
     *   maxSize = "5000k",
     *   mimeTypes = {"text/comma-separated-values", "application/pdf", "text/csv", "application/csv", "application/excel", "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.msexcel", "application/octet-stream","text/plain"},
     * )
     */
    private $file

    /* ... */
}
```

the function that can do the serialization is

```
$serialize = serialize($docuement);
$encodingDoc = $serviceUtils->encode($serialize, $this->container->getParameter('key_encrypt'));
```

when I upload a pdf file ou cvs file, everything work great, but when I try to upload html file, I get an error

```
Serialization of 'Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile' is not allowed
```

any help please

Comment: We need to post here your code, otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: modifyed with my code

Answer (score 1):

Since you say it works well with `*.psd` and `*.csv`but doesn't work with `*.html` it might be just because of the `@Assert\File` annotation which allows mimetypes for `psd` and `csv` but doesn't allow `html` files.

HTML files should be identified by `text/html` mimetype so try adding `text/html` to the list of allow mime types in `@Assert\File` and see if it helps.

Comment: the problem is when calling serialize function